# NSMutableArray not adding object! (using addObject: nor addObjectsFromArray)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray

```
(IBAction)adicionarPastas:(id)sender {

    AbreBrowser *abre = [[AbreBrowser alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *arquivosRecebe = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[abre abreBrowser]];
    [abre release];

    [arquivos addObjectsFromArray:arquivosRecebe];    
    [arquivosTableView reloadData];

    [arquivosTableView setDataSource:self];
}
```

Well, arquivos is declared on this files header as:

```
NSMutableArray *arquivos;
```

`[abre abreBrowser]` indeed returns a `NSArray`.

My problem is `[arquivos addObjectsFromArray:arquivosRecebe];` doesn't work.
I also tried `addObject` and it gives me the same result, i.e. nothing.

When I feed arquivos like this:

```
arquivos = [abre abreBrowser];
```

it works.
But when I do a `[arquivos addObject:Object]` or `[arquivos addObjectsFromArray:NSArray]` it doesnt feeds my `NSMutableArray` arquivos.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It appears that you are not allocating **arquivos** anywhere in your object's initialization before actually sending the addObjectsFromArray message to it.

Comment: oh my god, you`re right, thank you. after allocating it, it worked. how could i miss that???? i deserve a slap on my face. god....

Comment: :-) The answer was in your question itself; you said - *"when i feed arquivos like 'arquivos = [abre abreBrowser];' it works."*

Comment: This prevented me from banging my head into a wall for very long!

Answer (score 0):

So why don't you use that which works? `arquivos = [abre abreBrowser];`

Also, it seems you should switch these statements?

```
   [arquivosTableView reloadData];
   [arquivosTableView setDataSource:self];
```

To this:

```
   [arquivosTableView setDataSource:self];
   [arquivosTableView reloadData];
```

Comment: i didnt use the way that works because i want to keep adding objects into the NSMutableArray, and using the way that works was not possible. Thanks for your help too, the previous answer solved my problem, but i`ll take your sugestion and invert those lines.